# Any block logging beside Big Brother that don't use database?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there any pluging used for anti-griefing beside Big Brother that don't use MySQL and any other database?

I don't have MySQL or Postgre and I would like to log any block misplaced or lava / TNT.

Comment: If there is, it's going to be very slow, because a flat file format wouldn't scale too well to the amount of data that all the blocks removed/added would generate on a moderately sized MC server.

Comment: All existing block logger plugins use an external database service like MySQL. You say you "don't have" MySQL. Do you mean you *can't* use it where you have hosting, or you just don't have it already and could get it if you knew how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Log](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/sec-log-v0-7-1-a-lightweight-alternative-to-bigbrother-permissions-1060.9216/) plugin claims to be a lightweight alternative to BigBrother, and seems to work fairly well. It uses flatfiles, which over time may not scale well on a large server. It doesn't offer rollbacks, which could kill it for some people though.